# how to define a LottieDrawable?

Tags: android, lottie, fresco

It looks like `LottieComposition.Factory` is deprecated already. I'm wondering how I can define a `LottieDrawable`? I could not find the documentation for this.

The reason I want a Drawable is because I want to pass a Lottie animation into fresco as a placeholder drawable.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but since I too came against the same problem and managed to find how to do it, might as well share it.

So a `LottieCompositionFactory` can be used to obtain a `LottieComposition` from a `raw` `.json` file, **URL**, or assets in the `assets` folder etc. using the corresponding function as given in the [API reference](https://www.mvndoc.com/c/com.airbnb.android/lottie/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieCompositionFactory.html), and then use the composition to assign it to a `LottieDrawable`.

For example, using a `.json` file

```kotlin
val animDrawable = LottieDrawable()
LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawRes(requireContext(), R.raw.anim_file).addListener {comp ->
    animDrawable.composition = comp
}
```

Then the drawable can be used anywhere a `Drawable` can be passed.

Answer (score 0):

the right answer is :

```
val animDrawable = LottieDrawable()
LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawRes(context, R.raw.loading_banner).addListener { comp ->
    animDrawable.composition = comp
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code example:-

```
final private LottieDrawable ld = new LottieDrawable();
Field f = swipeRefreshLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCircleView");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            ImageView imgVW = (ImageView)f.get(swipeRefreshLayout);
            ld.setBounds(0, 0, 64, 64);
            @SuppressLint("WrongThread") LottieResult<LottieComposition> result = LottieCompositionFactory.fromAssetSync(App.activity, "LottieSpinner.json");
            ld.setComposition(result.getValue());
            ld.setRepeatCount(LottieDrawable.INFINITE);
            imgVW.setImageDrawable(ld);
```